# My own block class defined in community cood pool. But it not work with relevant template (Magento version 1.9 extension development)

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to create small extension for displaying string in Product page Magento 1.9.2. So I did it using "community" code pool for effecting block (block name ="product.info") in catalog.xml layout but it did not work till. I think my code is right but I don't sure whether all relevant folders (Controller, helper, Observer) are included or not in my module(Dinod). Please any one can help me to create this extension by using "community" code pool in Magento 1.9.2.

I failed to get expected output by testing my extension using "community" code pool. But same extension structure work fine after using "core" code pool. So I stored my module(Dinod) inside "app/code/core/Mage" folder and that time worked properly.

This code structure does not generate any expected output through frontend (product page).

- app/etc/modules/Jpdn_Dinod.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Jpdn_Dinod>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </Jpdn_Dinod>
  </modules>
</config>
```

- app/code/community/Jpdn/Dinod/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Jpdn_Dinod>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </Jpdn_Dinod>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Jpdn_Dinod module="Jpdn_Dinod">

                    <file>jpdn_dinod.xml</file>

                </Jpdn_Dinod>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <global>


<!-- adding block "Jpdn_Dinod_Block_Product_View" -->

        <blocks>
              <jpdn_dinod>

                  <class>Jpdn_Dinod_Block_Product_View</class>

              </jpdn_dinod>
        </blocks> 

<!-- adding block "Jpdn_Dinod_Block_Product_View" -->


    </global>

</config>
```

- app/code/community/Jpdn/Dinod/Block/Product/View/dinod.php

```
class Jpdn_Dinod_Block_Product_View_Dinod extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function dinod_methodblock()
     {
         $name = "Informations from dinod_methodblock in Jpdn_Dinod";
         return $name;
     }
}
```

- app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/jpdn_dinod.xml

```
<layout version="1.0.3">

    <catalog_product_view>

        <reference name="product.info">

            <!-- 
            <block type="dinod/product_view_dinod" name="mage.view.dinod" as="mage.dinod" template="dinod/product/view/dinod.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Dinodddd works</value></action>
            </block>
            -->

            <block type="jpdn_dinod/product_view_dinod" name="jpdn.view.dinod" as="jpdn.dinod" template="dinod/product/view/dinod.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Dinodddd works</value></action>
            </block>

        </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/dinod/product/view/dinod.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->dinod_methodblock(); ?>
```

Above code structure does not generate any expected output through frontend (product page).

After I created new block class file in "app/code/core/Mage" and edited code in template file as below so I got expected output without any error.

- app/code/core/Mage/Dinod/Block/Product/View/dinod.php

```
class Mage_Dinod_Block_Product_View_Dinod extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function dinod_methodblock()
     {
         $name = "Informations from dinod_methodblock in Mage_Dinod";
         return $name;
     }
}
```

- app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/jpdn_dinod.xml

```
<layout version="1.0.3">

    <catalog_product_view>

        <reference name="product.info">

            <block type="dinod/product_view_dinod" name="mage.view.dinod" as="mage.dinod" template="dinod/product/view/dinod.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Dinodddd works</value></action>
            </block>


            <block type="jpdn_dinod/product_view_dinod" name="jpdn.view.dinod" as="jpdn.dinod" template="dinod/product/view/dinod.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Dinodddd works</value></action>
            </block>

        </reference>

    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

But I want to get same output only using "community" code pool instead of using "core" code pool for effecting block (block name ="product.info") in catalog.xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your block definition is wrong

```
<blocks>
      <jpdn_dinod>

          <class>Jpdn_Dinod_Block_Product_View</class>

      </jpdn_dinod>
</blocks>
```

this is not how you should declare it. Remove product_view

```
<class>Jpdn_Dinod_Block</class>
```

this should be enough